# Transfer WeChat history from Mac to iPhone (not the other way around)

Tags: mac, backup, iphone, history, chat

My phone broke and was forced to get a new phone without backing up my WeChat chat history. However, because I always use the MacOS app, I still have my entire history on my Mac. But I can't seem to find a way to transfer that history from my Mac to my new iPhone, only the reverse. Is there a way to create a backup from my the data on my Mac instead of from the data on my phone?

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: Not an iPhone user, but as a thought, perhaps your WeChat data was backed up to iCloud and you could restore it from there?

Comment: @music2myear I've tried to use WeChat's built in backup features, but they only allow you to create a backup from your phone. I have also looked into where the data is stored on my computer. I found it, but there's not much that I can do with it without understanding if and how I can move that data to my iPhone. I assume that moving it would require the iPhone app to allow it, which it may not. I'm also waiting on a response from WeChat customer support.

Comment: @Anaksunaman WeChat isn't included in the list of apps for iCloud support. I don't think it's an option.

Answer (score 1):

As of version 3.5.5, you now have the option to migrate your history from desktop (PC/Mac) version and back to the mobile app. It is similar to the backup/restore process, but it is a new feature called "Migration". I have been waiting for this for a few years too.

[image]